# How to get the Pinia state from server side to client side in VUE with Inertia SSR?

Tags: vue.js, vite, server-side-rendering, inertiajs, pinia

I have a frontend project (website / webshop) running on Laravel 10 with Vue3 components. The Inertia plugin serves my props, Ziggy is used for routing, Pinia for state management, Vite to compile assets, Laravel Breeze was used for initial setup.
I'm new to all of Vue, Inertia, Ziggy and Pinia so there might be a lot wrong with my setup. I'm glad for all the help I can get.

There's one main component (Layout.vue) that imports child components depending on the content that is loaded by Layout.vue through an axios API request.
I started setting up SSR (Server Side Rendering) for this project. I've read that it makes sense to  store data in "Stores" to use outside the lifecycle of the component so we can load the data on server side and re-use it on client side without having to re-request things from the API a second time.

What I understood is that Pinia would take care of that pretty well. (It's the reason I tried using the package in the first place) My problem though is that I can't get Pinia to put the serialized data loaded from Layout.vue into the generated HTML on server side to then read out on the client side for further use. All the guides and examples I found are set up a little different here and there and I don't have enough knowledge to combine the info into a working solution. (Or don't know how to as ChatGPT to give me the answers I can use)

My setup looks approximately like this (simplified):

vite.config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        legacy({
            targets: ['defaults', '> 0.05%'],
        }),
    ],
});
```

app.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../scss/app.scss';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';
import i18n from "@/i18n.js";

import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

let pinia     = createPinia()

import HeaderComponent from         '../vue/HeaderComponent.vue';
import LoadingComponent from        '../vue/LoadingComponent.vue';
import ErrorComponent from          '../vue/ErrorComponent.vue';


// Helper function for the async object
function createAsyncComponent(loader) {
    return {
        loader,
        loadingComponent: LoadingComponent,
        errorComponent: ErrorComponent,
        delay: 0,
        timeout: 3000,
    };
}

const FooterComponent = defineAsyncComponent(
    createAsyncComponent(() => import("../vue/FooterComponent.vue"))
);
const PlainText = defineAsyncComponent(
    createAsyncComponent(() => import("../vue/components/PlainText.vue"))
);

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`../vue/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('../vue/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {

        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(i18n)

            .component('HeaderComponent',                HeaderComponent)
            .component('LoadingComponent',               LoadingComponent)
            .component('ErrorComponent',                 ErrorComponent)
            .component('FooterComponent',                FooterComponent)

            .component('Text',                           PlainText)

            .use(pinia)

            // I would assume somewhere here the Pinia state should be added to my html

            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

ssr.js

```
import {createSSRApp, defineAsyncComponent, h} from 'vue';
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import createServer from '@inertiajs/vue3/server';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';
import i18n from "@/i18n.js";

import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

let pinia     = createPinia()

import HeaderComponent from         '../vue/HeaderComponent.vue';
import LoadingComponent from        '../vue/LoadingComponent.vue';
import ErrorComponent from          '../vue/ErrorComponent.vue';

// Helper function for the async object
function createAsyncComponent(loader) {
    return {
        loader,
        loadingComponent: LoadingComponent,
        errorComponent: ErrorComponent,
        delay: 0,
        timeout: 3000,
    };
}

const FooterComponent = defineAsyncComponent(
    createAsyncComponent(() => import("../vue/FooterComponent.vue"))
);
const PlainText = defineAsyncComponent(
    createAsyncComponent(() => import("../vue/components/PlainText.vue"))
);

createServer((page) =>
    createInertiaApp({
        page,
        render: renderToString,
        title: (title) => `${title}`,
        resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`../vue/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('../vue/**/*.vue')),
        setup({ App, props, plugin }) {
            return createSSRApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
                .use(plugin)
                .use(ZiggyVue, {
                    ...page.props.ziggy,
                    location: new URL(page.props.ziggy.location),
                })
                .component('HeaderComponent',                HeaderComponent)
                .component('LoadingComponent',               LoadingComponent)
                .component('ErrorComponent',                 ErrorComponent)
                .component('FooterComponent',                FooterComponent)

                .component('Text',                           PlainText)

                // I would assume somewhere here we would read out the Pinia state from the generated HTML

                .use(pinia)

                .use(i18n);
        },
    })
);
```

Controller.php function

```
public function index (Request $request, $locale, $slug = '') {

        $data['locale']                         = $locale;

        return Inertia::render('Layout', $data);

    }
```

app.blade.php (Used as base by Inertia)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

    <head>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @routes

        @vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/vue/{$page['component']}.vue"])

        @inertiaHead

    </head>

    <body>

        @inertia

    </body>

    <!-- Pinia serialized state data here? -->

</html>
```

Layout.vue

```
<template>

    <header-component :pages="pages" :page="page" :page_details="page_details" :userData="userData">

    </header-component>

    <main class="py-4">

        <div class="container">

            <template v-if="!isLoading && !errorContent" v-for="(view, view_index) in page.views">

                <component v-if="view.template" v-bind:is="view.template.component" :view="view" :page_details="page_details" :userData="userData" :getUserData="getUserData" :key="`${componentKey}-${view_index}`" @reset="resetError">

                </component>

            </template>

        </div>

    </main>

    <div id="pinia_store" data-store="serializedData">

    </div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import {useMenuStore} from "../js/stores/menu.js";

export default {
    name: "Layout",
    props: [
        'page_details',
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            page: [],
            pages: [],
            errorContent: '',
            componentKey: 0,
            menuStore: useMenuStore(),
            serializedData: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getPage() {

            // Get path
            let url             = '/'+this.page_details.url_path;

            // Get locale from path
            this.$i18n.locale   = url.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');

            // Remove locale from path that's sent to api
            let path_send       = decodeURIComponent(url.replace('/'+this.$i18n.locale, ''));

            await axios.post(this.page_details.api_url +'/route/search', {
                    lang: this.$i18n.locale,
                    path: path_send
                })
                .then((response) => {

                    this.isLoading  = false

                    // Display error message
                    if (!response.data.page || !response.data.page.published) {
                        throw 404;
                    }

                    this.page       = response.data.page


                }).catch(() => {

                    this.errorContent   = '<article><div class="content"><h1>404 | Not found</h1</div></article>'

                });

        },
        async getMenu() {

            await this.menuStore.fetchMenu(this.page_details.api_url);
            this.pages      = this.menuStore.pages

            this.serializedData = JSON.stringify(this.menuStore.pages, null, 2)

        },
    },
    async serverPrefetch() {

        await this.getPage()
        await this.getMenu()

    },
    mounted() {

        this.getPage()
        this.getMenu()

        /* // This part could be for reading out the serialized data from the html.
        const serializedElement = document.querySelector('#pinia_store');
        if (serializedElement) {
            try {
                const parsedData = JSON.parse(serializedElement.getAttribute('data-store'));

                console.log(parsedData)

                this.menuStore.data = parsedData;
                this.pages = parsedData;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error parsing serialized data:', error);
            }
        }

         */

    },
}
</script>
```

menu.js (Store)

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from "axios";

export const useMenuStore = defineStore({
    id: 'menu',
    state: () => ({
        pages: [],
        loading: false,
        error: null
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchMenu(api_url) {

            this.pages = []

            this.loading = true

            try {

                await axios.get(api_url+'/menu')
                    .then((response) => {

                        this.pages = response.data

                    })

            } catch (error) {

                this.error = error

            } finally {

                this.loading = false

            }

        },
    }
})
```

In the code samples here I've removed a lot of unnecessary stuff for simplicity sake. (e.g. there's many more components imported and other functions that are irrelevant here) If anything is missing, let me know so I can add it as well.
I've tried using the "Menu" api call to get a start with Pinia state management and stores. The page content itself I've not touched yet, but I assume that's mostly copy + pasting from the "Menu" setup once that works.

What I understood is that we should load data in the serverPrefetch() function for ssr, put it into the store, (until here I think it's working) then let Pinia put the store into our rendered HTML (e.g. into a window variable), read it out from the HTML on client side (app.js) and repopulate the store, then use it in the mounted() function of the component.

I've already tried a few ways to put the Pinia state into the HTML but all fails.

- Adding the store request to the ssr.js doesn't make sense in my opinion as it depends on data within Layout.vue. Also considering I would want other components with api calls using Pinia store as well that should only execute when the component is actually used.
- Adding a  tag with a window variable and serialized data within Layout.vue doesn't work as it's not an allowed tag within the component.
- Using a data() as in the example above would only reset the html when loading the client side. etc.

Did I misunderstand the whole concept of how Pinia and SSR work or ..?

Comment: did you fix the issue  ?

Comment: @AhmadzIssa Not yet unfortunately.

Comment: I suggest you to watch inertia js  in laracast it will help a lot